# document.querySelector("#pay").click()

Tags: javascript, forms, click

Help set the delay before clicks what options you can write I don't really understand

```
<form class="form-for-pay" action="https://merchant.webmoney.ru/lmi/payment.asp?at=authtype_8" method="post" id="paypal_form_submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT" value="20" />
    <input type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYMENT_DESC" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYMENT_DESC_BASE64" value="0J/QvtC/0L7Qu9C90LXQvdC40LUg0YHRh9C10YLQsA== " />
    <input type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYEE_PURSE" value="Z000000000000" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="70" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="2" />
    <button type="submit" style="display:none;" class="btn btn-success" id="pay">
        Pay
    </button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.querySelector("#pay").click()
</script>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: need to delay the auto click .click() timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getElementById` instead `querySelector` because it's much faster. [getElementById vs. querySelector](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/11). You can use `querySelector` if there is no ID and you have to use e.g. `getElementsByClassName` which isn't supported <= IE8

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById("pay").click()
}, 2000);
```